# Is it ok to wear beautiful dress in front of non mahram?

Tags: women, non-mahram

Is it permissible for a woman to wear patternful, beautiful, gorgeous,flowery, attractive, bright, colorful, eye-catching dresses in front of non mahram?

Answer (score 2):

A women must not be a point of attraction of all the men around instead she should be covered from head to toe in front of non-mahrams.
Talking for men's perspective, I would like no other man to praise the beauty of my wife, moreover I would be really concerned if her appearance is drawing attention.

From my personal point of view, a wife is a safe house for the husband and only for him, she should dress only to be more attractive for her husband because when he will find beauty at his home, he will not go out looking for women and nafs.

Below is a link where you can find details and reference from where the rules of sharia for women are driven.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/82994/womans-awrah-in-front-of-other-women-and-mahrams

Jazak Allah

Comment: You didn't really answer if it is haram but I like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding,
As long as her awrah is covered, it is not haram to wear beautiful dress. I don't know about any verse of Al-Quran or hadith  which prohibits it. However, it is **not recommended**.

It is not recommended because, it will lead to adultery, which is one of the biggest sins. But if your intention is to attract any man or your crush and get them to talk with you and be your boyfriend, then it is haram.

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, "The (reward of) deeds, depend upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended. (*Bukhari, 6689*)

Answer (score 0):

It's haram for a woman to adorn herself because  the purpose of hijab is to conceal the woman's beauty by adorning herself she is still attracting men and tempting them …and not to show off their adornment…” [al-Nur 24:31]

Abu Dawud (565) narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “Do not prevent the female slaves of Allah from attending the mosques of Allah , but let them go out unadorned.” (Classed as authentic by al-Albani in Irwa al-Ghalil, 515)  
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/39570/can-muslim-women-wear-coloured-hijab  see this link for more information